# PythonWin occasionally gives an error on opening

Tags: python, pywin32

I occasionally (seemingly at random) get the following error, as I open PythonWin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 181, in InitInstance
    import interact
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\interact.py", line 31, in <module>
    import winout
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\winout.py", line 233, in <module>
    import pywin.scintilla.view
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\view.py", line 722, in <module>
    LoadConfiguration()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\view.py", line 708, in LoadConfiguration
    configManager = ConfigManager(configName)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\config.py", line 123, in __init__
    line, lineno = self._load_keys(subsection, fp, lineno)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\config.py", line 270, in _load_keys
    sc, flag = keycodes.parse_key_name(key)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\keycodes.py", line 91, in parse_key_name
    return vk, flags | this_flags
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Sometimes closing the IDE and opening it solves the problem, sometimes I need to wait for a while before doing so, and sometimes I have to restart my PC.

I am using `pywin32 build 219`, and running on Windows 10.

How can I solve this once and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. It's still not fixed. But the following workaround reliably helps: switch your keyboard layout to English before running PythonWin and it will start successfully. Always working for me.

Comment: This is not a *partially-successful* workaround, it's a *full-blown-solution* workaround. I can trigger the error by changing the keyboard layout to non-English (shift+alt), and revoke the error by changing the keyboard layout back to English (shift+alt again). Thank you, I finally know how to deterministically resolve this problem!!!!!

Comment: Did anyone dug thoroughly inside this bug? Is it related with pywin or scintilla or corepython?

Comment: @SergeyKarpukhin I had a chance to take a look and submitted the fix: [pywin32 #1264](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1264).